# mysql_fetch_array - group results

Tags: php, mysql

CMS Model:

```
public static function getSiteLinks($page)
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM cms_links WHERE page = '{$page}'";

    return mysql_query($query);
}
```

`cms_links` table has the following: `id, page, section_sub, title, link`

In my view I have:

```
$links=CMS::getSiteLinks('home-page');

while($link = mysql_fetch_array($links))
{
    echo $link['section_sub'];
    echo $link['title'];
}
```

The field `section_sub` defines what 'group' the link belongs to. I want to output the results from the above query, grouped by `section_sub`. So for example after each group, a line break is inserted and the next group begins.

Answer (score 0):

First add `ORDER BY section_sub` to your query.

Now, before the loop, add `$currsection = null;`.

Inside the loop, the first thing you should do is:

```
if( $link['section_sub'] != $currsection) {
    $currsection = $link['section_sub'];
    echo "<hr /><h2>".$link['section_sub']."</h2>";
}
```

Done.

Comment: Cheers mate. How can I enclose each 'section_sub' within a DIV?

Comment: `echo <div>` before the loop, `</div>` after the loop, and `</div><div>` when the section changes.

Comment: Cheers. I'm having trouble with this - can you update your example to illustrate this please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Arrange the result by section_sub:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM cms_links WHERE page = '{$page}' ORDER BY section_sub";
...
$prevsub = '';
while($link = mysql_fetch_array($links))
{
    echo $link['section_sub'];
    echo $link['title'];

    if($prevsub != '' && $prevsub != $link['section_sub'])
        echo '<br/>';
    $prevsub =  $link['section_sub'];
}
```