# Show query results in separate divs when section id changes

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a query

```
mysql_select_db($database_auditing, $auditing);
$query_sections3 = sprintf("SELECT tblanswer.questionid AS answerqid,
                                tblanswer.answerid AS answerid, 
                                tblanswer.answer AS answer, 
                                tblquestion.questionid AS questionid, 
                                tblquestion.questiontext AS questiontext, 
                                tblquestion.questionid AS quesid, 
                                tblquestion.questiontypeid AS questiontype, 
                                tblquestion.sectionid AS sectionid, 
                                tblscore.score1 AS score1, 
                                tblscore.score2 AS score2, 
                                tblscore.score3 AS score3, 
                                tblscore.score3 AS score3, 
                                tblscore.score4 AS score4, 
                                tblhelptext.helptext AS help, 
                                tblsection.sectionname AS sectionname 
                            FROM tblanswer 
                            LEFT JOIN tblquestion ON tblanswer.questionid = tblquestion.questionid 
                            LEFT JOIN tblscore ON tblquestion.questionid = tblscore.questionid 
                            LEFT JOIN tblhelptext ON tblquestion.questionid = tblhelptext.questionid 
                            LEFT JOIN tblsection ON tblquestion.sectionid=tblsection.sectionid 
                            WHERE tblanswer.auditid=%s 
                            ORDER BY tblquestion.sectionid",  
                        GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['auditid'], "int"));

$sections3 = mysql_query($query_sections3, $auditing) or die(mysql_error());

$totalRows_sections3 = mysql_num_rows($sections3);
```

which pulls relevant questions from the database and builds a questionnaire relevant to the site.

Each question is relevant to a certain section.

So what I'm trying to do (and failing at miserably) is to get the results from the query above to appear in the relevant part of the accordion I'm using for the questionnaire without having to use a nested query within each div (which is causing me issues with entering the given results into the db).

Thanks to everyone who contributed to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392583/mysql-fetch-array-group-results?rq=1).

I have managed to get the accordion to siplay each question within it's own tab but what I'm trying to achieve is to get all the relevant questions within same tab.

Here's the accordion code:

```
<?php $prevsub='';
$purpleronnie=0;
 while ($row_sections3=mysql_fetch_assoc($sections3)) {

     if ($row_sections3['sectionid'] !=$prevsub) {
         ?>

<div class="AccordionPanel">
<div class="AccordionPanelTab"><?php echo $row_sections3['sectionname'];?></div>
<div class="AccordionPanelContent">

<br />
<h5>Please answer the questions below to the best of your ability. For help, hover over the help icon, help text will appear in the box to the right of the screen.</h5>
<?php }?>

<table class="table2" align="center">
<tr>

<th><?php echo $row_sections3['questiontext'];?> <input type="hidden" name="qnumber[]" value="<?php echo $row_sections3['questionid'];?>" />
</th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="answerid[<?php echo $purpleronnie;?>]" value="<?php echo  $row_sections3['answerid'];?>" size="1" />

<?php if ($row_sections3['questiontype']=="1") { ?> 
<input type="text" size="25" name="answer[<?php echo $purpleronnie;?>]" value="<?php echo $row_sections3['answer'];?>" />

<?php } ?>

</table>    

</div>
</div>
<?php $purpleronnie++;
 if ($prevsub!=''&&$prevsub!=$row_sections3['sectionid'])
 $prevsub=$row_sections3['sectionid']; }?>
```

Any suggestions of how to alter the above to get the accordion div's to change everytime the section id increases, rather than for every question?

Many thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to sort the stuff by section id then you can build an array of data sectioned off by the section_id first and then you would loop through that and build your divs etc. The code below is based on your example code and prob not the most elegant but it will do what you want granted the data comes in as assumed. If this is not 100% what you need it will at least give you a place to start. Also, be careful with your closing tags. You missed closing your table column and row in the example code you posted.

```
$purpleronnie=0;
$data = array();

// sort your questions into "buckets" first
while ($row_sections3=mysql_fetch_assoc($sections3)) {
    // store that row of data in the correct sectioned off container
    $data[$row_sections3['sectionid']][] = $row_sections3;
}

// do nothing if we have no data! 
if(empty($data)) exit('woops! no results in this section!');

// now loop through these results and build your divs
echo '<div class="AccordionPanel">';

foreach($data as $sectionid => $rows){
    // grab the section name of the first row to use for the main section tabs
    $section_name = $rows[0]['sectionname'];
    echo 
        '<div class="AccordionPanelTab">'.$section_name.'</div>
         <div class="AccordionPanelContent">
            <br />
            <h5>Please answer the questions below to the best of your ability. 
                For help,hover over the help icon, help text will appear in the 
                box to the right of the screen.</h5>
            <table class="table2" align="center">';

    // now just loop through the rows in this section and fill in the stuff
    foreach($rows as $row){
      echo 
          '<tr>
               <th>'.$row['questiontext'].'
                   <input type="hidden" name="qnumber[]"
                          value="'.$row['questionid'].'"/>
               </th>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="answerid['.$purpleronnie.']" 
                          value="'.$row['answerid'].'" size="1" />';

        // do your conditional here
        if($row['questiontype']=="1") {
            echo '<input type="text" size="25" name="answer['.$purpleronnie.']" 
                         value="'.$row['answer'].'" />';
        }

        // make sure you close your rows!
        echo '</td></tr>';
    } // end foreach row of questions

    // close of question table and accordion panel content
    echo '</table></div>';

    // increment your counter thing
    ++$purpleronnie; 
}// end foreach sectionid

// close the accordian panel container
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Hi EmmanuelG, thank you so much for your response - with a bit of tweaking it works brilliantly (and sorry about the missing cell/row endings, I was posting in a hurry trying to get to a train!